# How does an "agency" differ from a "company"?

Tags: word-choice

When should a *company* be called an *agency*?
Typically advertising and recruitment companies call themselves agencies, is there a reason other than tradition for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An agency is a company that acts on behalf of another company — as an *agent*. For example, an advertising agency has clients for whom it sells advertising. McDonald's sells fast food to the public, so it is merely a company. It has an advertising *agency*, however, to create its commercials.

Similarly, a recruitment agency provides a service for employers, and so on.

Comment: +1, that's right! Like the travel agencies that work for the travelling companies, right?

Answer (score 6):

The distinction is that agencies act for others, while not all companies do so.
Check out this definition for agency: [A business or service authorized to act for others](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agency).